# ionic build android failed giving error on window 8

Tags: android, angularjs, ionic-framework

Hello I am working with ionic Framework When I am using

```
ionic build android
```

giving Error

```
Error: cmd: Command failed with exit code 1 Error output:
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Unable to start the daemon process.
This problem might be caused by incorrect configuration of the daemon.
For example, an unrecognized jvm option is used.
Please refer to the user guide chapter on the daemon at https://docs.gradle.org/
2.14.1/userguide/gradle_daemon.html
Please read the following process output to find out more:
-----------------------
Error occurred during initialization of VM
Could not reserve enough space for 2097152KB object heap


* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug
option to get more log output.
```

java version

```
java version "1.8.0_121"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_121-b13)
Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM (build 25.121-b13, mixed mode)
```

I get a lot of answer but problem still is same.

Answer (score 0):

The warning tell you that there's not enough memory for JVM. To fix the error increase the amount of memory in the gradle.properties file in android project by set the jvm options as the following:

```
org.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx1024m -XX:MaxPermSize=256m
```

Answer (score 0):

I resolved this problem  increase the amount of memory in the

gradle.properties file in android project by set the jvm options as the following:

org.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx1024m -XX:MaxPermSize=256m

But it is not working for me then

**Go to Start → Control Panel → System → Advanced system settings → advanced(tab) → Environment Variables → System Variables → New:**

```
Variable name:_JAVA_OPTIONS 
 Variable value: -Xmx512M
```

Comment: This is working if it in dev mode but not in production i think. Let say you have compile the ionic project in apk, the ionic will look at gradle.properties not in the local pc.